# Firebase phone number verification completely on the backend

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been using Firebase for a while and have successfully used it to verify phone numbers in past projects.

Now I'm trying to implement it completely on the backend because at my current project the end user (phone app) doesn't have internet access but the backend (the user is connected to) has.

My plan was:

1. The user is entering their phone number and sending it to my backend
2. The backend should send the phone number to firebase and send the client an SMS with the verification code
3. The client enters the verification code and sends it to my backend to verify

I wasn't able to find this and I'm not sure if it is supported. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Auth does not support this.  The APIs are driven from the client app, which is always where credentials are established.

If you need a way to verify a phone number only from a backend, you'll need to use another service.  I'm sure you can find some using a web search.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use it as front-end third party login service like sign with google etc... with use of [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#web-version-9)